# Java OpenCV Text Detection

Tags: java, opencv

I would like to detect and recognise numbers in an image and the programming language has to be Java. I was playing around with OpenCV and came across a new text detection and recognition feature in 3.0:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp

The problem is that I'm using 2.4 for my project, and even in 3.0 I can't seem to find a proper Java wrapper for this feature. Any guesses, how could I proceed? My other idea is to use Cascade Classifiers to train digits.

Comment: remove the `c++` tag if it's not a `c++` question

Comment: Use OpenCV in C++ through JNI calls. So you can use all OpenCV functions

Comment: The latest version of OpenCV does not seem to export those functions to the bindings: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/include/opencv2/text/erfilter.hpp#L210
You can either rely on the native interface and link with your Java program via JNI, or contribute to the project so that future versions export a text detection API.

Comment: Do you know if the text detection feature has been added to the Java bindings?